# Why is this incandescent light bulb working under water?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electrons, electric-current

[image]

The bulb is directly connected to 220V supply and is put into this glass container containing normal tap water.

Why is this bulb working under the water?
What about the ionisation of water molecules and why is there no obstruction occuring in the working of the bulb?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are concerned because the leads are shorted by the water, and hence you expect the circuit breaker to engage.

Sure, the water contains ions and thus conducts electricity, but even a saturated salin solution is nowhere as conducting as e.g. copper. That means, by Ohm's law, that the current through the water is very limited. In fact, the conductivity of the filament inside the light bulb is magnitudes higher. Thus there is no reason why the current through the water should trip the circuit breaker. It also doesn't trigger a RCD, because the current is not flowing away to ground, unlike when for example a hair dryer is dropped into a bathtub.

Be mindful though that even very small currents can trip up or arrest a heart. Thus contact with electrified water is highly discouraged unless you know exactly what you are doing.